# How can I get datacontext from hight level datacontext in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have class A and B:

```
    public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _ina;
    public string InA 
    {
        get
        {
            return _ina;
        }
        set
        {
            _ina = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("InA"));
            }
        }
    }
    public A()
    {
        InA = "INA";
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class B : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _inb;
    public string INB
    {
        get
        {
            return _inb;
        }
        set
        {
            _inb = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("INB"));
            }
        }
    }
    public B()
    {
        INB = "B_inb";
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

and a xaml(local is a namespace alias which class A and B are in):

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:B/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.DataContext>
            <local:A/>
        </StackPanel.DataContext>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=InA}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=INB }"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I know the first `TextBlock` will get the right value but the second one can't. But how can I get `DataContext` make the second `TextBlock` get the right value from grid's `DataContext`, not from stackpanel's `DataContext`?

Comment: I know how to do it: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.INB,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"/>` But how it works?

Comment: how about having a ViewModel for the Window/UserControl that contains both A and B instance ? So that you don't need to specified DataContext per control. I wonder u r not doing MVVM correctly if you need to specified different DataContext in a view.

Comment: @cscmh99 Thanks for your suggestion. As you said, I change the ViewMode to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly figured out yourself,

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.INB,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"/>
```

will work.
What this is doing is going up the visual tree until it finds an ancestor of type `Grid`, and then looks for a property in that ancestor called `DataContext.INB`. In this case the Grid's data context would be class B and INB the property defined within it.